# Color cycler example in matplotlib documentation is cryptic (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, iterator

Would someone be so kind as to explain to me how this particular example works, taken from the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/#persistent-cycles) under the section Persistent Cycles?

Essentially they create color cyclers, which I am not sure if they are factory functions or iterators or normal functions or objects. Somehow you can make a generator out of them with `iter(my_cycler)` that is finite and an itertools.cycle generator with `my_cycler()`. This is just over my head how this works.

So my question is: why can you do `iter(my_cycler)` and it gives something finite and why can you do `my_cycler()` and it gives the same thing but infinite (it loops).

```py
>>> from cycler import cycler
>>> cyl = cycler(color=['r', 'g', 'b'])

>>> type(cyl)
cycler.Cycler

>>> import cycler
>>> cycler.Cycler.__mro__
(cycler.Cycler, object)

>>> type(cyl())
itertools.cycle

>> type(iter(cyl))
generator
```

When I type:

```py
>>> next(cyl)
TypeError: 'Cycler' object is not an iterator
```

but somehow this here works:

```
>>> for s in cyl:
...     print(s)
 
{'color': 'r'}
{'color': 'g'}
{'color': 'b'}
```

The other question is the strange application of defaultdict. `styles = defaultdict(lambda : next(finite_cy_iter))`. I think I roughly understand it but I want to be sure: Every time a key is not in the dict, `(lambda : next(finite_cy_iter))()` is called or something. According to the documentation on defaultdicts, you have to give it a function and in this case `function = (lambda : next(finite_cy_iter))`. So I guess every time a key is not in the dict `function` gets called, which is actually a disguised iterator which gives you the next dict out of the cycler, which then gets stored as the value for that key.

#### Here is the section in the matplotlib documentation:

Persistent Cycles
It can be useful to associate a given label with a style via dictionary lookup and to dynamically generate that mapping. This can easily be accomplished using a defaultdict

```py
In [40]: from cycler import cycler as cy

In [41]: from collections import defaultdict

In [42]: cyl = cy('c', 'rgb') + cy('lw', range(1, 4))
```

To get a finite set of styles

```py
In [43]: finite_cy_iter = iter(cyl)

In [44]: dd_finite = defaultdict(lambda : next(finite_cy_iter))
or repeating

In [45]: loop_cy_iter = cyl()

In [46]: dd_loop = defaultdict(lambda : next(loop_cy_iter))
```

This can be helpful when plotting complex data which has both a classification and a label

```py
finite_cy_iter = iter(cyl)
styles = defaultdict(lambda : next(finite_cy_iter))
for group, label, data in DataSet:
    ax.plot(data, label=label, **styles[group])
```

which will result in every data with the same group being plotted with the same style.

Comment: Casual reader, please understand that the OP statement "_Essentially they create color cyclers_" is misleading ፨ ፨ `cycler` objects can provide at each iteration a dictionary of different Artist properties (e.g. for a Line2D you can specify not just the color but also the line width, line type, marker shape etc etc) so that in the unfortunate instance you are asked to plot tens of different curves on the same graph (no one but your boss could desire such a mess ;-), each one has visual characteristics that make it individual.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant to say line properties cyclers generally speaking. I think the most common use case, in particular for me, is to make colors in a particular, more logical order (for example to show day by day progressions in one plot).

Answer (score 1):

Re the first part of the question,

> So my question is: why can you do `iter(my_cycler)` and it gives something finite and why can you do `my_cycler()` and it gives the same thing but infinite (it loops).

the `cycler` class behaves like that because it's defined like that, look at this simpler example to see what I mean…

```
In [13]: class callable_list(list): 
    ...:     def __call__(self): 
    ...:         from itertools import cycle 
    ...:         return cycle(self)                                                       

In [14]: l = callable_list((1,2))                                                         

In [15]: l                                                                                
Out[15]: [1, 2]

In [16]: it_l = iter(l) ; cy_l = l()                                                      

In [17]: for _ in range(3): print(next(it_l))                                             
1
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e4324d8268a6> in <module>
----> 1 for _ in range(3): print(next(it_l))

StopIteration: 

In [18]: for _ in range(3): print(next(cy_l))                                             
1
2
1
```

and what is the "why" of this behavior?

We want to place an arbitrary number of Artists in an Axes and we want to be able to uniquely identify them, using different properties (not just color) to differentiate them.

The default is to call the Cycler object, and use the infinite cycle returned, allowing for some level of repetition but without the risk of a `StopIteration` exception being raised.

The alternate approach, showed in the example cited by the OP, is the use of `iter` on the Cycler object, this way repetitions are avoided but the coder has to anticipate the possibility of a `StopIteration` exception.

---

*Addendum* addressing [an OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760061/color-cycler-example-in-matplotlib-documentation-is-cryptic-python/63760994#comment112751772_63760994)

---

> When I do `cyl[1]` with my Cycler object. I get: `ValueError: Can only use slices with Cycler.__getitem__` What does that mean?

It means that the coders of the `cycler` module decided that a Cycler object can be addressed only by slices…

> `cyl[1:2]` works, but strangely gives two elements back instead of one, `cyl[1:1]` gives back one element

This is not what I see… define two Cycler and their outer product

```
In [1]: from cycler import cycler 
   ...: c, w = cycler(c=['r','g','b']), cycler(lw=range(1,5)) 
   ...: cw = c*w 
   ...: print(c, w, cw, sep='\n')                                                         
cycler('c', ['r', 'g', 'b'])
cycler('lw', [1, 2, 3, 4])
(cycler('c', ['r', 'g', 'b']) * cycler('lw', [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

and start with the single Cycler, first `[1:2]`, for me it returns a single value

```
In [2]: c[1:2]                                                                            
Out[2]: cycler('c', ['g'])
```

and then `[1:1]`, again a single value, that is an empty Cycler

```
In [3]: c[1:1] # empty cycler                                                             
Out[3]: cycler('c', [])
```

note that this is similar to slicing a list, in any case the value of the expression is a single object, a list, possibly an empty list… nothing new.

Finally, let's see what happens when slicing the outer product but first let's see what is inside it

```
In [5]: for i, d in enumerate(cw): print(i, d)                                            
0 {'c': 'r', 'lw': 1}
1 {'c': 'r', 'lw': 2}
2 {'c': 'r', 'lw': 3}
3 {'c': 'r', 'lw': 4}
4 {'c': 'g', 'lw': 1}
5 {'c': 'g', 'lw': 2}
6 {'c': 'g', 'lw': 3}
7 {'c': 'g', 'lw': 4}
8 {'c': 'b', 'lw': 1}
9 {'c': 'b', 'lw': 2}
10 {'c': 'b', 'lw': 3}
11 {'c': 'b', 'lw': 4}
```

Now we address it by slicing

```
In [6]: cw[3:9]                                                                           
Out[6]: (cycler('c', ['r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b']) + cycler('lw', [4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]))
```

The result is a single Cycler, the inner product of two Cycler, corresponding when *unfolded* to the positions 3÷8 of the enumerated printout above.

Finally, let's address `cw` using `[3:3]`, i.e., an empty slice (spoiler, nothing good is going to happen!)

```
In [7]: cw[3:3]                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1bf3cb52c570> in <module>
----> 1 cw[3:3]

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cycler.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    219             trans = self.by_key()
    220             return reduce(add, (_cycler(k, v[key])
--> 221                                 for k, v in six.iteritems(trans)))
    222         else:
    223             raise ValueError("Can only use slices with Cycler.__getitem__")

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cycler.py in __add__(self, other)
    241             raise ValueError("Can only add equal length cycles, "
    242                              "not {0} and {1}".format(len(self), len(other)))
--> 243         return Cycler(self, other, zip)
    244 
    245     def __mul__(self, other):

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cycler.py in __init__(self, left, right, op)
    116         """
    117         if isinstance(left, Cycler):
--> 118             self._left = Cycler(left._left, left._right, left._op)
    119         elif left is not None:
    120             # Need to copy the dictionary or else that will be a residual

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cycler.py in __init__(self, left, right, op)
    133             self._right = None
    134 
--> 135         self._keys = _process_keys(self._left, self._right)
    136         self._op = op
    137 

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cycler.py in _process_keys(left, right)
     66         The keys in the composition of the two cyclers
     67     """
---> 68     l_peek = next(iter(left)) if left is not None else {}
     69     r_peek = next(iter(right)) if right is not None else {}
     70     l_key = set(l_peek.keys())

StopIteration: 

In [8]:
```

In my humble opinion, this last *feature* very much resembles a bug…

Comment: Wow, very nice explanation with very nice code! So essentially cycler objects are "callable lists"? That's crazy. Hard to wrap my head around that. But the code that you show makes it clear that it's possible to construct something like that. 

When you call them they keep repeating, but when you stuff them into iter, they get "expressed" and act like a normal list?

Comment: When i do    
cyl[1] with my cycle object. I get:    
ValueError: Can only use slices with Cycler.__getitem__ What does that mean? cyl[1:2] works, but strangely gives two elements back instead of one. cyl[1:1] gives back one element.

Comment: @Jim Don't know why but I've missed your comments… my apologies.  I'll try to address them asap (don't hold your breath ;-)